# An error occurs when saving pages and datatypes content in the Composite C1 console

Tags: c1-cms

I'm experiencing an issue in the Composite C1 console when saving data - pages, data types, media, anything that has a form.

After editing and saving data the console reloads the form but with all fields empty. The loading spinner keeps going until the user presses escape to force it to stop. It seems like some sort of binding doesn't work as intended, but there are no errors in the JavaScript console. The C1 Server Log shows the following three entries, however, from `UiControlContainer`:

```
Posibility of data corruption detected. Unexpected lazy bound state information from client. Expected 'true' or 'false', got '' for post back field 'FlowUI$Document$DocumentBody$TabPanels_lazybindingactivatedPreview'. Will try to bind on child controls.
Posibility of data corruption detected. Unexpected lazy bound state information from client. Expected 'true' or 'false', got '' for post back field 'FlowUI$Document$DocumentBody$TabPanels_lazybindingactivatedMetadata'. Will try to bind on child controls.
Posibility of data corruption detected. Unexpected lazy bound state information from client. Expected 'true' or 'false', got '' for post back field 'FlowUI$Document$DocumentBody$TabPanels_lazybindingactivatedSettings'. Will try to bind on child controls.
```

Inspecting the actual HTTP request to`FlowUi.aspx` in Chrome's inspector shows that the three fields are indeed sent as part of the POST body:

```
FlowUI$Document$DocumentBody$TabPanels_lazybindingactivatedSettings:false
FlowUI$Document$DocumentBody$TabPanels_lazybindingactivatedMetadata:false
FlowUI$Document$DocumentBody$TabPanels_lazybindingactivatedPreview:false
```

Has anyone else seen these errors or had the same behaviour?
Anyone else on a Web Application Project that does NOT have this issue?

The console is running on C1 4.1.5058.34326, and the application is a Web Application Project in Visual Studio.

Comment: FYI: I have cross-posted your question to the [Composite C1 discussion board at CodePlex](https://compositec1.codeplex.com/discussions/554485).